# Argument isn't numeric in bitwise or (|) at. Why?

Tags: perl

I am using code from [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=55250):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl;
my $flags =  "";
fcntl( STDIN, F_GETFL, $flags) || die $!;
$flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl( STDIN, F_SETFL, $flags) || die $!;
```

But get next error:

```
Argument "\0O§"­U\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0..." isn't numeric in bitwise or (|) at /home/user/inetd-script.pl line 9.
```

`$flags` is initialized by `fcntl` call. Tell me please why this error occur.

And how to fix it.

**UPD**
Perl cookbook 7.20.2 initialized it as empty string.

[image]

Comment: what version of perl are you running?  seems like you are seeing an fcntl bug; it should not be setting $flags to a string.  I'm guessing that if `$flags` is initialized to 0 this doesn't happen.

Comment: @ysth: perl 5.24.1. Full info: http://paste.scsys.co.uk/585134

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bitwise operators have two flavors, string and numeric.  If either operand is numeric, or the "bitwise" feature[^1] is enabled, it is treated as a numeric bitwise.  In that case, if an other operand is a string, it is converted to a number, and a warning is generated if it doesn't look like a number.

You should be initializing $flags to 0, not `""`.

[^1]: the "bitwise" feature makes the normal bitwise operators only do numeric bitwise, and adds new string bitwise operators such as `|.`.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning the [new, string, versions of the bitwise operators](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5280delta.pod#String-and-number-specific-bitwise-ops-are-no-longer-experimental).

Comment: changing `""` to `0` helps. Thanks

Comment: @ysth: heh. Perl cookbook 7.20.2 initializes it as empty string too. [screenshot](http://i.piccy.info/i9/575f1cad4beab45ed8f0c22c28dbc7f3/1561481192/36875/1316591/_.jpg)